# SQL query two queries and union

Tags: sql, join, db2, union

I've these two approaches for a problem and they look kind of okay to me. Is there a better way to do this? Please advise.

X,Y,Z are same for both queries

 
 
**Two queries and add the values:**
 
select sum(columnA1), sum(columnA2) from tableA 
where columnA3 = X and columnA4 = Y and columnA5 = Z;
 
select sum(columnB1) from tableB
where columnB3 = X and columnB4 = Y and columnB5 = Z;

 
 
**Union All:**
select sum(columnA1), sum(columnA2), sum(columbB1)
from (select columnA1, columnA2, null from tableA
where columnA3 = X and columnA4 = Y and columnA5 = Z
union all 
select null, null, columnB1 from tableB
where columnB3 = X and columnB4 = Y and columnB5 = Z) unionresult

Comment: These queries do not do the same thing.  Provide sample data and desired results to figure out what query you really want.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why it wont output the same thing? check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a78a9/9 . I get the same output 3, 7, 5

Comment: . . Your first "query" returns two result sets.  The second returns one result set.  These are not the same thing.

Comment: oh yes! sorry about the ambiguity. when I use two queries, I've some extra work, like putting the result of 1st query and result of 2nd query together. In the second approach I don't have to that extra work. So basically it comes down to efficiency of executing two separate queries or an union query and most threads I see here or elsewhere don't have a binary answer. It all comes down to table schema and volume of data. I'm going to study the execution plan in my database and make a decision. Thanks

Comment: . . Add the results in the database.  It is a bad idea to split business logic between different applications, if it can readily be accomplished using only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your 2 options will produce the same 3 numeric results, the only real difference is in the delivery (either as 2 queries or as a single, combined, query).

I cannot really know which suits your purpose best, but you are adding a tiny overhead to get get a combined result.

Here is another possible alternative for a combined result but I don't think it's any better than the union all approach you show (& it could even be worse).

```
SELECT
      SUM(columnA1)
    , SUM(columnA2)
    , (
            SELECT
                  SUM(columnB1)
            FROM tableB
            WHERE columnB3 = X
                  AND columnB4 = Y
                  AND columnB5 = Z
      ) as sum_columnB1
FROM tableA
WHERE columnA3 = X
      AND columnA4 = Y
      AND columnA5 = Z
;
```

Comment: I compared the execution plan of my union query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a78a9/9 vs yours http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a78a9/11 and it looks like yours is better. 2 steps in total.

Comment: Indeed it does look better, good of you to follow-up. Will this be your accepted answer then?